# Material-ui - Google autocomplete address

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use Material-Ui in my React application and I am trying to add an input google autocompletion for addresses into my form.

Here is my problem, I have found this library https://github.com/ErrorPro/react-google-autocomplete which integrates the google maps API for places, but the input looks like the most basic input, i.e with 0 style.

For now my code looks like this :

```
<Autocomplete
onPlaceSelected={(place) => {
    console.log("Place selected", place);
}}
types={['address']}
/>
```

This code works fine and prints the address, the simple problem is that the input has the default look and feel, and I want it to have the material-ui one.

I have also looked at this library https://github.com/ydeshayes/googlePlaceAutocomplete which seems to be exactly what I want but I can't make it work and it seems to be not much documented. So I tried to write a code like this :

```
<GooglePlaceAutocomplete 
    onChange={this.onAutoCompleteInputChangeFct.bind(this)}
    onNewRequest={this.onClickLocationFct.bind(this)}
    name={'location'}
/>
```

But with this code I have my input but when I type in it the suggestions so it seems that it doesn't work.

So my question is: Is there a way to wrap the AutoComplete component into the TextField element from material-ui ?

Comment: Yes, I've done this. I'm trying to extract out what I've done to a jsFiddle. I'll post an answer when it's ready.

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for using Material UI TextFields along with Google Places autocomplete? I haven't found a solution short of implementing the autocomplete manually.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, you grab a ref to the `<input />` DOM element rendered by the `TextField`, then in componentDidMount() you do your `google.maps.new places.Autocomplete()` as normal. In the `Autocomplete`'s `place_changed` event, you'll either do something with that like pass it to a Redux action or a callback/handler that was supplied by the parent (e.g. onPlaceChanged)

Here is a jsFiddle with a little bit of CSS added to make it look nice. It assumes Google places API is already loaded in browser: https://jsfiddle.net/e0jboqdj/3/

```
class LocationSearchBox extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (typeof google === 'undefined') {
      console.warn('Google Places was not initialized. LocationSearchBox will not function.');
      return;
    }

    const { country, onPlaceChanged } = this.props;
    const { places } = google.maps;

    let options;

    if (country) {
      options = {
        componentRestrictions: { country }
      };
    }

    const input = this.locationSearch;

    input.setAttribute('placeholder', '');

    if (!input._autocomplete) {
      input._autocomplete = new places.Autocomplete(input, options);

      input._autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
        onPlaceChanged && onPlaceChanged(input._autocomplete.getPlace());
      }.bind(input._autocomplete));
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <span>
        <TextField ref={ref => (this.locationSearch = ref.input)} hintText="Search nearby" />
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm I have problems when I try to execute your code : 
First, I have to change the 'place_changed' function to a classic one instead of one with the arrow and when `<TextField ref={ref => (this.locationSearch = ref.input)} hintText="Search nearby" />` is executed the console tells me that ref is null... 
Do you have any idea ? And more, when I type text in the Textarea I have an error in the console saying Unexpected batch number... that keeps popping every time I type in the Textarea